# Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 1001

Tags: silverlight

Please have a look at the below xaml in silverlight

```
<Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="50" ScaleY="50" />
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <Grid Height="400" Width="600">
              **//Here I have so many objects placed.**
            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Here I have used `ScaleTransform ScaleX="50" ScaleY="50"`. The application gives the following error for the large value of ScaleX and ScaleY. Can anyone tell me why it is happening so in silverlight and how to get rid of this?

> Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
>   Code: 1001
>   Category: RuntimeError
>   Message: AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
>   MethodName: